# How to check $\phi$ is linear?

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

Assume $\phi: \mathbb R ^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is $C^\infty$ satifying
\begin{equation}
\phi(\lambda x)=\lambda \phi(x), \;\; \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R},
\end{equation}
then how can we conclude that $\phi$ is linear?